# Changed value of variables in debugging

Tags: c

I'm trying to fill two dimensional array
When debugging for-loop, value of `a` and `num` is changed.
I don't know why value is changed.

```
int main(void)
{
    int num,t; 
    int count = 1; 
    int a = 0, b = 0; 
    int arr[num][num]; 

    printf("Input Number : ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    
    t = num;    
    
    for(int i = 0 ; i < t ; i++)    
    {
        arr[a][b] = count;
        b++;
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is because of the unexpected behavior. Since num is uninitialized, the array might be zero sized or random sized. Therefore, you are changing a memory that you should not access, while changing array values in for loop. You should not initialize array with integer numbers. You may want to take a look at "Dynamic Memory Allocation" to initialize variable sized arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining your array with undefined values since num has not been assigned a value.  You should assign num a value before defining the array and you should at least see more expected results.

Answer (score 1):

Your program needs the num to be assigned a value before declaring the array that is supposed to store the value contained in num variable. Otherwise, it won't execute properly.

```
printf("Input Number : ");
scanf("%d",&num);
```

before

```
int arr[num][num];
```

Hope that helps!